# Html contact form button is inactive

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have used an html contact form template found online for my static website hosted on aws.
The html contact form in its head section is linked to a js script with a formula, provided together with the html template.
Behind that on aws I have created a lambda formula to fetch the massages via api gateway and use ses to forward them to an email address, that part should be ok.
Unfortunately it does not seem to work and I think it's something related to the html part as the button seems inactive.
Here below the html script (just hid the datasite key):

```js
function submitToAPI(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var URL = "https://XXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/001/contact-us";

  var Namere = /[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z]/;
  if (!Namere.test($("#name-input").val())) {
    alert("Name can not less than 2 char");
    return;
  }
  var mobilere = /[0-9]{10}/;
  if (!mobilere.test($("#phone-input").val())) {
    alert("Please enter valid mobile number");
    return;
  }
  if ($("#email-input").val() == "") {
    alert("Please enter your email id");
    return;
  }

  var reeamil = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6})?$/;
  if (!reeamil.test($("#email-input").val())) {
    alert("Please enter valid email address");
    return;
  }

  var name = $("#name-input").val();
  var phone = $("#phone-input").val();
  var email = $("#email-input").val();
  var desc = $("#description-input").val();
  var data = {
    name: name,
    phone: phone,
    email: email,
    desc: desc
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://abc1234.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/01/contact",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: "true",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),


    success: function() {
      // clear form and show a success message
      alert("Successfull");
      document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
      location.reload();
    },
    error: function() {
      // show an error message
      alert("UnSuccessfull");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#fcf-form {
    display:block;
}

.fcf-body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    max-width: 50%;
}

.fcf-form-group {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.fcf-input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
}

.fcf-form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.fcf-form-control:focus {
    border: 1px solid #313131;
}

select.fcf-form-control[size], select.fcf-form-control[multiple] {
    height: auto;
}

textarea.fcf-form-control {
    font-family: -apple-system, Arial, sans-serif;
    height: auto;
}

label.fcf-label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.fcf-credit {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    color: #545b62;
}

.fcf-credit a {
    color: #545b62;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.fcf-credit a:hover {
    color: #0056b3;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.fcf-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .fcf-btn {
        transition: none;
    }
}

.fcf-btn:hover {
    color: #212529;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fcf-btn:focus, .fcf-btn.focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}

.fcf-btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff;
}

.fcf-btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0069d9;
    border-color: #0062cc;
}

.fcf-btn-primary:focus, .fcf-btn-primary.focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0069d9;
    border-color: #0062cc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(38, 143, 255, 0.5);
}

.fcf-btn-lg, .fcf-btn-group-lg>.fcf-btn {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.fcf-btn-block {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.fcf-btn-block+.fcf-btn-block {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

input[type="submit"].fcf-btn-block, input[type="reset"].fcf-btn-block, input[type="button"].fcf-btn-block {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <link href="contact-form.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <div class="fcf-body">

    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="form-control.js"></script>
    </head>
    <form id="contact-form" method="post">
      <h4>Name:</h4>
      <input type="text" style="height:35px;" id="name-input" placeholder="Enter name here…" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" /><br/>
      <h4>Phone:</h4>
      <input type="phone" style="height:35px;" id="phone-input" placeholder="Enter phone number" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" /><br/>
      <h4>Email:</h4>
      <input type="email" style="height:35px;" id="email-input" placeholder="Enter email here…" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" /><br/>
      <h4>How can we help you?</h4>
      <textarea id="description-input" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your message…" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"></textarea><br/>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXX" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"></div>
      <button type="button" onClick="submitToAPI(event)" class="btn btn-lg" style="margin-top:20px;">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</center>
```

Can anyone let me know what am I missing/doing wrong so that the contact form works?
Thank you

Comment: Is there any error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: no it's ok. I have copied it entirely from an official aws partner post and just substituted the url.

Comment: It seems to run here.

Comment: You don't get alerts if you leave the inputs blank?

Comment: exactly, I don't get any alerts in any case, even if I fill up the fields

Comment: It's as if the html and js don't communicate